# std::ofstream not writing a BST to file

Tags: c++

I am trying to write the contents of a BST to a text file, but it will not work for me, and I don't know why.

```
void outAccess(NodeTree* root)
{
    ofstream outFileP5("salidaOrdenadaAccess.txt");
    if(outFileP5.is_open())
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            outFileP5.close();
            return;
        }
        // Viajar izquierda
        outAccess(root->right);

        // visitar nodo
        cout << "Mando" << root->line << endl;
        outFileP5 << root->line << " "<< "Numero de accesos " << root->data << endl;

        // Viajar derecha
        outAccess(root->left);
    }else
    {
        cout << "no jalo" << endl;
    }
}
```

I thought that would definetly work for me since I've done it before with double-linked lists.

Answer (score 3):

You are re-opening and truncating the file in every single call to `outAccess`. Or, if the file is locked and fails to open during a recursive call, then the recursion will output "no jalo" and return.

I suggest you change your function to accept an output stream, and make the caller responsible for opening the file. This is more flexible and powerful.

```
void outAccess(std::ostream& s, NodeTree* root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        outAccess(s, root->right);
        s << root->line << " "<< "Numero de accesos " << root->data << "\n";
        outAccess(s, root->left);
    }
}
```

Then, the caller would do something like this:

```
ofstream outFileP5("salidaOrdenadaAccess.txt");
if (outFileP5.is_open())
{
    outAccess(outFileP5, root);
}
else
{
    cout << "no jalo" << endl;
}
```

You can even use the same method to send the tree to standard output:

```
outAccess(std::cout, root);
```